Encountering Memory Exceeded Limit on Matrix Visualisation in PowerBI
I'm working on improving the performance of a calculation of the penetration rate. Taking our sales invoice fact table that goes down to sales invoice lines, the logic is:

Group by sales invoice number and filter on all those for which the sum is larger than a parameter that is passed
Count the number of sales invoices that pass the previous criteria
Count the number of customers that have this number of invoices over a certain number that is also a parameter that is passed.

Creating a table with countries and a drilldown on regions with this measure as the Values is causing some huge performance issues. I would expect some performance issues from the nature of what is calculated, but not having to wait minutes for this to load.
The two parameter tables have the following structure:
Min Order Value
| Value |
| ------|
| 150   |
| 300   |
| ...   |
Min Order Count
| Value |
| -------- |
| 1|
| 2|
| ... |
Here is the relevant DAX:
Penetration Rate = 

VAR MinOrderAmount = VALUES('_PARAMS_Penetration Min Order Value (€)'[Penetration Min Order Value] )
VAR MinOrderCount = VALUES('_PARAMS_Penetration Min Order'[Penetration Order Count])


VAR InvoiceFilter = 

    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice Fact'[Customer Bill To Key])
        , FILTER (
            ADDCOLUMNS(
                SUMMARIZE (
                    FILTER (
                        ADDCOLUMNS(
                            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                                'Sales Invoice Fact'[Sales Invoice Key]
                                , 'Sales Invoice Fact'[Customer Bill To Key]
                            )
                            , "@InvoiceSum"
                            , CALCULATE ([IMP Net Sales (€)])
                        )
                        , [@InvoiceSum] >= MinOrderAmount
                    )
                    , 'Sales Invoice Fact'[Customer Bill To Key]
                )
                , "@InvoiceCount"
                , DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales Invoice Fact'[Sales Invoice Key])
            )
            , [@InvoiceCount] >= MinOrderCount
        )
    )

VAR CustomersWithOrder =
    CALCULATE (
        [IMP Customer Count],
        FILTER ( 'Customer', [IMP Net Sales (€)] > 0 )
    )

VAR PenetrationRate =
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( '_PARAMS_Penetration Min Order Value (€)'[Penetration Min Order Value] )
                        && HASONEVALUE ( '_PARAMS_Penetration Min Order'[Penetration Order Count] ),
        DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE ( InvoiceFilter ),
            CALCULATE (
                CustomersWithOrder,
                ALLEXCEPT (
                    'Products',
                    'Products'[Brand Name],
                    'Products'[Product Channel]
                )
            ),
            BLANK ()
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )

RETURN PenetrationRate

I've followed advice to use ADDCOLUMNS with SUMMARIZE/SUMMARIZECOLUMNS whenever possible.
After multiple retries at rewriting this measure, this is where I am.
I have tried separating out the measure into multiple measure that I then import into this one but that doesn't seem to do much.
I haven't tried precalculating data but I am not sure what I can here as we need to be able to filter on other fields.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very comfortable in SQL but DAX is still fairly new to me.
